# Match strings in C using * as wildcard

Tags: c, regex, wildcard

I know about the regex implementations out there, including the POSIX version which is widely available for C. However, it is not available everywhere. And I don't need the full regex expressiveness.

So I was looking for a simple way to match a single C-string using the single wildcard '*'. E.g.

`a*, b*c, *d`

where '*' means match any number of characters.

Comment: Something like `fnmatch` is found on most UNIX-style platforms, with similar native Windows alternatives around that might work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to look into [glob(3)](https://www.mirbsd.org/man3/glob) and possibly [fnmatch(3)](https://www.mirbsd.org/man3/fnmatch) instead of using POSIX regexps.

Otherwise, just escape all chars that need escaping in RE (such as `.`) and convert `*` into `.*` and tack on `^` and `$` as needed (and change `^.*` and `.*$` into the empty string).

Comment: int fnmatch(const char *pattern, const char *string, int flags); was almost exactly what I needed. Although not guaranteed to be available everywhere, but close enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking many of those regex implementations are open-source, so you can probably get some ideas from them.

As you have it, I think you can probably easily build something using strchr and/or strstr, but they wouldn't necessarily be "proper" regexes in that they wouldn't be greedy (for instance matching b*c against bacac would find the first c instead of the second).  Depending on your needs, that may be enough.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that browsing the source for a full regex implementation is not going to be a fruitful exercise.